# Write data to Kafka in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch, spring-kafka

Fresh new to the Kafka, recently I am trying to get data from spring batch and then write to the Kafka, but I have no idea how to do it.
Could someone help me to figure out how to write the data to the Kafka? 
Here is the demo code that I write with SpringBatch to get data:

@Configuration
public class FileReader {

```
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("flatFileWriter")
private ItemWriter<? super Demo1> flatFileWriter;
@Bean
public Job FileReaderJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("FileReaderJob").start(FileReaderStep()).build();
}
private Step FileReaderStep() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("FileReaderStep").<Demo1,Demo1>chunk(100).reader(flatFileReader())
            .writer(flatFileWriter).build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Demo1> flatFileReader() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    FlatFileItemReader<Demo1> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Demo1>();
    reader.setResource(new  ClassPathResource("Demo1.csv"));
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setNames(new String [] {"id","first","last"});
    DefaultLineMapper<Demo1> mapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
    mapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    mapper.setFieldSetMapper(new FieldSetMapper<Demo1>() {

        @Override
        public Demo1 mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
            Demo1 demo1 = new Demo1();
            demo1.setId(fieldSet.readLong("id"));
            demo1.setFirst(fieldSet.readString("first"));
            demo1.setLast(fieldSet.readString("last"));

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return demo1;
        }
    });

    mapper.afterPropertiesSet();
    reader.setLineMapper(mapper);

    return reader;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The upcoming Spring Batch v4.2 GA will provide support for reading/writing data to Apache Kafka topics. You can already try it out with the [4.2.0.RC1 release](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.2.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNew).

For the `KafkaItemWriter`, you will need to configure a `KafkaTemplate`. Here is an example of the writer:

```
@Bean
public KafkaItemWriter<String, Demo1> kafkaItemWriter(KafkaTemplate<String, Demo1> kafkaTemplate) {
    return new KafkaItemWriterBuilder<String, Demo1>()
            .kafkaTemplate(kafkaTemplate)
            .build();
}
```

You can also take a look at the [Spring Tips installment](https://spring.io/blog/2019/05/15/spring-tips-spring-batch-and-apache-kafka) about Kafka support in Spring Batch by Josh Long.